# Problem with HttpService POST

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to send some data to PHP using HTTPService POST but for some reason it's not working.

The same example works with GET but not with POST:

```
private function start():void{
    var param:Object = {};
    param.date = "2010-10-10";
    userRequest.send(param);
    userRequest.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, result);
    userRequest.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, fault);
}

private function fault(e:FaultEvent):void{
    trace(e.message);
}

private function result(e:ResultEvent):void{
    trace(e.result);    
}

<mx:HTTPService id="userRequest"
                url="http://localhost:8888/api"
                useProxy="false" 
                method="POST"/>
```

And here's the PHP code:

```
$d = $_POST['date'];
echo $d;
if($d == ""){
    trace("Date not found!");
    die();
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> "Error #2032: Stream Error. URL:
>   http://localhost:8888/api"

But when I change the method in HTTPService to GET and in PHP I get the result as expected - PHP sends back the date:

> 2010-10-10

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you check if request is sent correctly (with Firebug or other preferred tool)

Comment: Uh, actually this is an AIR app! I traced the error result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This started working after I replaced

> http://localhost:8888/api

with

> http://localhost:8888/api/index.php